# Spark : SQLContext : How to control the number of partitions when loading data from json?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I am trying to load some data that is in json format into an SQLContext using a machine with 36 cores. However when I try to load the data using :

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("/folder_name/*")
```

spark only partitions the data into 4 sections and only use less than 20 percent of the total processing power of the machine. As you can see below I am loading the data from 4 files.

```
INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
INFO SparkContext: Starting job: json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) with 4 output partitions
```

What I want to be able to do it to load the data from these 4 files but for spark to repartition the data to 36+ partitions so it will use all the cores while loading the data. At the moment this data load operation takes quite some time since it is only using about 4 cores and less than 20% of the processing power of the machine.

Comment: Could you please add more details? Like where are you running your app on (standalone? yarn?), how did you configure spark driver/executor/properties...?

Comment: How about simply calling `repartition` on your `dataframe` and specify the exact number of partitions you want?

Comment: The issue may be that the files are compressed in a non-splittable format like gzip. With uncompressed files, or compressed splittable like bzip2, spark would create a partition per DFS block, but if it can't split them it would create one partition per file.

Comment: @markon : I am running it on standalone using "pyspark" executable and every thing is on default. glennie : that will not work in this situation since the above line of code triggers the data loading and processing. Partitioning the data after loading is not required here. Just need to speed up the loading of data into the dataframe. roberto : Once when I was trying to run the line of code it split the data into 7 partitions and started executing. So I think the system can be made to load the data using more than the number of gz files.

Comment: @roberto : Let me clarify what I said. I need to get the files to be split into more sections when its trying to insert the json data into the dataframe not exactly when copying the data over from s3.

Comment: Hey guys, managed to figure out how to get it done. Was a super duper obvious one that I did not see.... You first load the data into an RDD using `data = sc.textFile("/table_contents/*", 36)` and the use that to load the data using `df = sqlContext.read.json(data)`